# Special case of Elliott's Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, k-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be unital $AF$-algebra. By Elliott's theorem we know that if there an order isomorphism $\psi: K_0(A) \rightarrow K_0(B)$ with $\psi([1_{A}]) = [1_{B}]$, then there exists an isomorphism $h : A \rightarrow B$ such that $h_{*} = \psi$.

My question is this is true for homomorphism? In other words, Let $A$ and $B$ be unital $AF$-algebras. Suppose that there is an order homomorphism $\alpha: K_0(A) \rightarrow K_0(B)$ such that $\alpha([1_{A}]) = [1_{B}]$. Is there homomorphism $h: A \rightarrow B$ such that $h_{*} = \alpha$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is true: See this paper https://www.researchgate.net/publication/264425120_The_Category_of_Bratteli_Diagrams by Elliot, Golestani and Amini, theorem 6.1. What you are asking is whether the $K_0$ functor is *full* when restricted to the subcategory of unital AF algebras and is co-restricted to the category of ordered abelian groups with unital, positive group homomorphisms as morphisms. This is exactly what the above paper shows in theorem 6.1. I think that it can also be proved by more elementary means, but I need to think a bit more about this.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the proof of Elliott's classification theorem in Rordam's blue book can be slightly modified to prove what you are asking, but of course one must check that all the lemmas are applicable. With a first look I didn't spot a problem to this, so I believe the proof can be mimicked:)

Comment: Yes, I checked it, too. Think everything is alright with a bit of effort.